# SQL Group Data with a Left Join to a Sub Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, aggregation

Any help would be appreciated.

I have an aggregate query to which I am adding a column via a sub-query (which also has an aggregation to it). But the query is not returning the correct results:

```
DECLARE @Period int 
DECLARE @Year int
SET @Period = 08
SET @Year = 2018

SELECT 
    ColA
    ,ColB
    ,PL.Month
    ,SUM(Period_Total) AS Period_Real
    ,SUM(bud.[Value]) AS Period_Estimate
    ,YTD_A.SubQuery_Estimate AS YTD_Real -- <This is the row of data with issues
FROM [dbo].[TableA] PL

LEFT JOIN [dbo].[TableB] bud
ON PL.ColA = bud.ColC AND PL.Period_Date = bud.[Period_Date]

--THIS JOIN IS WHERE I AM HAVING THE ISSUE
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT ColC,SUM(Value) AS SubQuery_Estimate --,month, year
    FROM [dbo].[TableB] 
    WHERE    Year =@Year AND Month BETWEEN 1 AND @Period
    GROUP BY ColC --,Month,Year
) YTD_A
ON YTD_A.ColC = PL.ColA 

WHERE PL.MONTH = @Period AND PL.Year = @Year
GROUP BY ColA,ColB,PL.MONTH, PL.Year
ORDER BY ColA,PL.Month
```

Any suggestions and help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: update your question add a proper data sample, the actual result and the expected  result

Comment: You need to add `YTD_A.SubQuery_Estimate` column in `Group By` for this query to even execute

Comment: Thank you both for your comment. @Pரதீப் that is bringing back the same value for each row of data

Comment: For each `ColC`, `SubQuery_Estimate` will be same. Please add sample data and expected result

Comment: I am making up the tables and the data

Comment: So you are making up the data.  What is the actual result and the expected result.

Comment: Grouping by `PL.Year` is going to be unnecessary (redundant) since you can only have a single value there anyway.

Comment: What is `ColB`? We can't guess too much about the query since we don't even know which table that comes from. Judging from the rest of the query I'm not sure you need it. Or possibly you need to include it in some of the joins?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    PL.ColA, @Period as "Month",
    MIN(CASE WHEN PL."Month" =  @Period THEN bud.Period_Total END) AS Period_Real,
    MIN(CASE WHEN PL."Month" =  @Period THEN bud.Value END) AS Period_Estimate,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PL."Month" <= @Period THEN bud.Value END) AS YTD_Real
FROM dbo.TableA AS PL LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TableB AS bud
    ON PL.ColA = bud.ColC AND PL.Period_Date = bud.Period_Date
WHERE PL."MONTH" <= @Period AND PL."Year" = @Year
GROUP BY ColA
ORDER BY ColA;
```

Here's a stab at it ignoring `ColB` since I think you may not need it. I've reduced it to a single join with some conditional aggregation.